# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when looping through nav items

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to try and generate a custom navigation structure within WordPress but I'm running into problems with the for loop. WordPress is telling me that `$menuitems` is not an array:

```html
<?php
  $menu_name = 'main_nav';
  $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
  $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
?>

<nav class="main-navigation col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<ul class="main-nav">
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;
    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
        $link = $item->url;
        $title = $item->title;
        // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>

    <li class="item">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title">
            <?php echo $title; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>

            <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                </li>

            <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
            </ul>
            <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
    </li>                           
    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

<?php $count++; endforeach; ?>

</ul>
</nav>
```

But I get the `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` coming from the for loop.

Here is the output of `var_dump( $locations )`, `var_dump( $menu )` and `var_dump( $menuitems )`:

```js
array(2) {
  ["primary"]=>
  int(15)
  ["menu-1"]=>
  int(15)
}
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Comment: From the documentation of the functions, this should work. Can you include output of `var_dump( $locations )`, `var_dump( $menu )` and `var_dump( $menuitems )`

Comment: Why did you remove all of the code from your question? That makes this question useless. Do not vandalize your questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your `var_dump`'s above, your problem appears to stem from the menu name not existing...

`$menu_name = 'main_nav';` is not a menu name that exists.

Your `var_dump` shows that the menu names that exist are: `primary` and `menu-1`

Change the `$menu_name` variable to a menu name that exists.